# C#: Directly Setting Subclass Properties with Inline Object Instantiation

Tags: c#, object, inline, instantiation

I realize there are other ways to skin this cat, but I am hoping someone can help me understand why, in C#, I cannot directly set subclass properties when instantiating a "main" object inline.

For example, if I have the following classes:

```
public class SubClass
{
  public string SubField { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
  public string MainField { get; set; }
  public SubClass Sub { get; set; }

  public MainClass()
  {
    Sub = new SubClass();
  }
}
```

I get an error if I attempt the following:

```
var main = new MainClass
{
  MainField = "Main Value",
  Sub.SubField = "Sub Value"
};
```

The errors I get, on the "Sub.SubField = ..." line, are:

```
* "Invalid initializer member declarator"
* "The name 'Sub' does not exist in the current context"
```

The following, of course, works:

```
var main = new MainClass
{
  MainField = "Main Value",
  Sub = new SubClass { SubField = "Sub Value" }
};
```

but, it's more cumbersome and, in my opinion, less encapsulated.

I am perplexed why C# does not recognize the declared object and/or how it knows that it hasn't been instantiated.  It is not so careful in other situations.

I'm sure I'm missing a major concept.  Anybody up to enlightening me?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting is illegal and doesn't make sense anyways, because `Sub` is a new object.  You can still achieve what you want (see Andy's answer).

Take a look at section 7.6.10.2 Object initializers in the C# language specifiation, which states that:

> An object initializer consists of a sequence of member initializers, enclosed by { and } tokens and separated by commas. Each member initializer must name an accessible field or property of the object being initialized, followed by an equals sign and an expression or an object initializer or collection initializer. It is an error for an object initializer to include more than one member initializer for the same field or property. It is not possible for the object initializer to refer to the newly created object it is initializing.

Comment: "It is not possible for the object initializer to refer to the newly created object it is initializing." is the clarification I was looking for.  I knew this, but was thinking of the "subclass" (er, "subobject") as just another property.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
var main = new MainClass { 
  MainField = "Main Value", 
  Sub = { SubField = "Sub Value" } 
};
```

The above code actually gets compiled to something along these lines:

```
var main = new MainClass(); 
main.MainField = "Main Value";
main.Sub.SubField = "SubValue";
```

I like the object initialization syntax better as its slightly less noisy, and because most devs are used to working with C# blocks, more likely that they'll keep everything together.

Also I advise making the Sub property on MainClass have private settablility.

Comment: Thank you, @Andy.  This achieves what I am calling (for lack of a more infomed word) "better encapsulation".  It, unfortunately, is still more cumbersome than I was hoping for, but thanks to @"Bryan Cosby" (and a little @SonicTheLichen), I understand better why what I want to do wont work.  (I'd +1 you, but that's still above my newbie rank.  I think Bryan provided the closest answer.)

Comment: @jweekes I'm not sure I follow; while maybe this solution isn't as terse as you'd like, it does what I thought you were asking.  I've updated my answer to show what you'd have to do without using object initialization, which I think is more cumbersome than using it.  In the above syntax, it IS refering to the newly created Sub object.

Comment: @Andy What I wanted was not to have to use object initializer syntax for the sub object--I am warming up to it now, though.  Your solution is the same as what I said I knew worked in the original post, except you smartly removed "new SubClass".  If I couldn't do it the way I wanted, I wanted to know why not.

Comment: @jweekes Ah, I understand now. I thought you were just not able to set properties on SubClass, I didn't know you really intented to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

First, that's not a subclass. It's a separate object that is exposed as a property...

To quote MS: Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to explicitly invoke a constructor.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: The last part is the key. You are creating a new MainClass instance, so you can set the properties of the MainClass object. Sub is an entirely different object, it doesn't make sense to set its properties from the MainClass inline constructor.

Comment: The OP can achive what he's looking for, it doesn't matter that Sub is an entierly different object.  Downvoted because your answer implies it's not possible.

Comment: I didn't imply it's not possible to initialize the property using an initializer, I simply explained why what he is trying to do doesn't work. The issue is that the constructor (which he assumes is getting called) isn't getting called when he uses an initializer.

Comment: Thanks, @SonicTheLichen, but I stepped through with debug, and the constructor IS called.  Unfortunately, that doesn't help my situation.